# Using 'if' or 'else' to navigate to a new view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making a Quiz app and am trying to find a way to end the quiz so that it will navigate to a score page.  I've tried using the NavigationLink but it doesnt work - could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

The complete code

```
@State private var round: Round?
@State private var question: Question?
@State private var answer: Answer?
@State private var roundIndex: Int = 0
@State private var questionIndex: Int = 0
@State private var correctAnswers: Int = 0
@State private var showingScore = false
@State private var scoreTitle = ""
@State private var score = 0
@State private var showingAlert = false
@State private var percentageScore = 0


    
var answers: [Answer] {
    return question?.answers ?? []
}
   

    
private func loadQuiz() {
    round = quiz.rounds.first
    question = round?.questions.first
    questionIndex = 0
    roundIndex = 0
    score = 0
    scoreTitle = ""
    showingScore = false
    showingAlert = false

}

private func onAnswerTap(_ answer: Answer) {
    if answer.correct {
        scoreTitle = "Correct"
        score += 1
    } else {
        scoreTitle = "Incorrect"
    }
    showingScore = true
}

private func nextQuestion() {
    showingScore = false
    questionIndex += 1
    
    guard let round = round else { fatalError() }
```

Here is where I've put the If or Else part

```
    if questionIndex < round.questions.count {
        question = round.questions[questionIndex]
    } else {
        NavigationLink(destination: ProgressStats()) {
            Text("Quiz Completed, Well Done!")
          }
        }
}
```

Then the rest of the code

```
var body: some View {
   

    
    ZStack {
       
        
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .opacity(0.5)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        
        


        
        VStack(spacing: 40.0) {
            

                
            
            Text(question?.question ?? "")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -100)
            

        
            ForEach(answers, id: \.answer) { answer in
                Button(action: { self.onAnswerTap(answer) }) {
                    Text(answer.answer)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.all, 30.0)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
                        .onTapGesture { self.onAnswerTap(answer)
                        }
                }
                .frame(height: 11.0)
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
            .alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
                Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(score)"),
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                        nextQuestion()}
               
                )
            }
        }
    .onAppear() {
        loadQuiz()
    }

                }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Score:")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .offset(x: 0, y: -12),
                        
                            trailing:
                           
                            Text("\(score)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                .offset(x: -225, y: -12))
                                   

}
```

}

Comment: "It doesn't work" - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: NavigationLink doesn't automatically switch to a new View. A User can click on it in order to get to a new view. Showing different content with if else works, but try to implement more code so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Could you give more context where this condition is located?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!  Without seeing any more of your code my guess would be you haven't wrapped this code inside a NavigationView:

```
NavigationView {
...
 if questionIndex < round.questions.count {
        question = round.questions[questionIndex]
    } else {
        NavigationLink(destination: Progress()) {
            Text("Quiz Completed, Well Done!")
          }
        }
...
}
```

Without a navigation view defined you won't be able to navigate.

**Edit**:

You added code but there’s no NavigationView.
Add it right above the ZStack:

```
var body: some View {
  
NavigationView {
```

Comment: Thank you - for more clarification I have put the full code up